# Deploy SharePoint app project and solution

Tags: 2013, deployment, sharepoint-addin

When I created a solution of SharePoint MVC app, it is deployed and working fine. This is a test purpose. However when I created a SP MVC app project in an existing solution, am not able to deploy the app. What all things I need to consider to deploy SP app project from a solution?

Comment: What do you mean with existing solution? Are you trying to add the App to an existing Solution that before that only contains an MVC project?

Comment: Already a project is there having multiple MVC projects. I need to add SP MVC App into that solution

Comment: Ok, I've not tried it that way around. Adding existing MVC apps to a SharePoint Provider Hosted app solution works though

Comment: Can you try reverse? Adding a sharepoint provider host and its wen MVC app into an existing solution?

Comment: Sorry, I have no time for experimenting right now :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add an new ***App for SharePoint 2013*** project to your existing MVC Web application

**I selected Provider Hosted App**

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Hit the F4 on your existing newly added App project and you will see the properties. Select the MVC web application that you want to associate with your provider hosted App project.

When done, SharePoint will automatically add relevant classes like `TokenHelper.cs` etc. into your existing MVC web application. You might have to perform some refactoring depending upon your MVC project.

Deploy and enjoy!